Grails Multitenancy Database connection issue
Grail version : 5.3.5
MySQL : 8
JDK: Open JDK 8
Project is using multi tenancy and using hicaricp along with MySQL. I have 100+ data sources and when application starts it shows 100+ connections in MySQL process list, showing 1 connection per data source.
Project is deployed in AWS EC2 instance. When horizontal scaling of ec2 is performed, with 3 ec2 instances running, minimum connections becomes 3*100+ in process list.
Is there any other way so that grails will use connection as required ? otherwise with more addition of ec2 instances, it will use all available connections.
Expecting to find approach where data source call will be made as required, instead of making all connection at project start up.
